# Does Gallina have an equivalent of Haskell's `$` or Ocaml's `@@`

Tags: coq, gallina

Does the Gallina language in Coq have a predefined operator that helps avoid parentheses like Haskell's `$` or OCaml's `@@`?

If not, is there a conventional one that people define using Notation?

Comment: I think something like this 
`Notation "f @@ x" := (f x) (at level 10, x at level 100).`
should be a good enough first approximation.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this, but it should work for a lot of contexts:

```
Notation "f @@ x" := (f x) (at level 10, x at level 100).
```

The gist of this is that we put the argument expression at the level `100` which is the highest level, meaning the parser kind of starts parsing the argument expression (`x`) as a standalone expression.

The level 10 is the level of function application, so you don't want to go below that because something like `hd 41 @@ [42; 43]` wouldn't parse.